# Question on limit of expression with absolute values

Tags: limits

I need a confirmation regarding my calculation on a specific limit at $x=1$.

$ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { x\sqrt { \left| { x }^{ 2 }-x \right|  }  }{ x-1 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { x\sqrt { x\left| { x }-1 \right|  }  }{ x-1 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { x\times \left| x \right| \times \sqrt { \left| { x }-1 \right|  }  }{ x-1 }  } $

From there, I need to separate at 1 from the left and from the right:

From the right:

$ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1+ }{ \frac { x\times \left| x \right| \times \sqrt { \left| { x }-1 \right|  }  }{ x-1 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1+ }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ \sqrt { x-1 }  }  } \rightarrow +\infty $

From the left (I'm not so sure):

$ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1- }{ \frac { x\times \left| x \right| \times \sqrt { \left| { x }-1 \right|  }  }{ x-1 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1- }{ \frac { { -x }^{ 2 }\times \sqrt { -x+1 }  }{ x-1 }  } \rightarrow ? $

For me, from the left, it does have the same limit as from the right, which leads me to think that the expression therefore has no limit.

Can you please confirm ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: "it does have the same limit as from the right, which leads me to think that the expression therefore has no limit": on the opposite, when left and right limits are equal, there is a limit! But your computation has a sign error.

Comment: Yes, the "limit" as we approach $1$ from the left is $-\infty$. You are working basically along the right lines. There is a typo/error in the final expression, on top you have $-x^2\sqrt{-x+1}$, there should be no $-$ sign in front.  By the way, your handling of absolute values is awkward. Replacing $1-x$ by $-x+1$ (which is the same thing) and putting a $-$ sign in front is a sign of confusion.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{|x-1|}}{x-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\rightarrow \infty, x\rightarrow 1+,$and  $\frac{\sqrt{|x-1|}}{x-1}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\rightarrow -\infty, x\rightarrow 1-$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that near $1$ i.e in a neighborhood of $1$ we have always $|x|=x$ whether $x\to 1^+$ or $x\to 1^-$ so the second limit would be $-\infty$.

Comment: You're right. So as it has not the same limit from the right and the left, can we say that it has no limit ?

Comment: What do you say even the limit from the left and right are both equal $+\infty$? Surely the limit doesn't exist.